# C: function returning pointer

Tags: c, function, pointers

I have a difficulty in a  conceptual problem

consider this code:

```
char *myfunc()
{
char *temp = "string";
return temp;
}

int main()
{
char* ptr = myfunc();
}
```

I can't understand why ptr points to "string" after the function call. 
myfunc() creates an address in the stack which has the value "string" and another address which has the address of "string".
When the function ends, the memory it had in the stack is freed so it should return a pointer pointing to an address that does not contain "string" anymore.

Comment: Where did you learn that "myfunc() creates an address in the stack"?

Comment: Since temp is a string literal, it is pointing to the ROM segment, which is usually in the Data section of memory, not on the stack.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The location of the `temp` variable is on the stack, but the location of the string literal (to which `temp` points) is not stored on the stack. All string literals have a lifetime of the full runtime of the program, and so pointers to a string literal can be passed around freely.

But you should really get in the habit of using `const char *` when pointing to string literals, as string literals can't be modified.

---

From ISO/IEC 9899:2011, §6.4.5/6:

> The multibyte character sequence is then used to initialize an array of **static storage duration**

(Emphasis mine)

When the specification says "static storage duration" it means that the lifetime is the same as the execution of the program.

Comment: Are you sure a pointer to string literal can be returned from a function? `temp` is automatic local variable.

Comment: @haccks Yes, the location of string literals are static through the runtime of the program. Their address won't change. Returning a pointer to `temp` (e.g. `&temp`) will however lead to UB since that variable will "disappear" when the function returns.

Comment: I think I am missing something here. It would be nice if you can quote some reference from standard.

Comment: @hacks: Where are you getting stuck on this? We all agree that the variable `temp` is created on the stack and is no longer available when the function returns, but what is your understanding of where the string literal is stored?

Comment: @haccks This is no different to returning a pointer to a global variable from the function, or indeed a local`int` for example; you can always return an object created on the function's stack frame (even structs, but except arrays of course); you can't return _pointers_ to such objects.

Comment: @JoachimPileborg; Of course it is stored in read only section of memory.

Comment: @szczurcio; Here `"string"` is an object and `temp` is pointer to it; that means `temp` can't be return :)

Comment: @haccks Remember that in C values are passed and returned *by value*, which means the value is copied. Returning a pointer means that the *pointer* is passed/returned by value, i.e. the pointer is copied.

Comment: @JonathanWood; Of course it is stored in read only section of memory.

Comment: Thanks, makes sense now. what other types of variables are stored in the Data/ROM?

Comment: It is perhaps significant here that pointers are not arrays.  It matters in this case because the the OP's code would *not* be correct if `temp` were instead declared `char temp[] = "string";`.

Comment: @JoachimPileborg; I forgot about that static storage duration. Make sense now. Thanks :)